# Identification of an important document

Tags: text-mining

I have a set of text documents in java .  I have to identify the most important document (just as what an expert would identify) using a computer.

eg.  I have 10 books on java , the system identifies Java complete reference as the most important document or the most relevant.(based on similarities with the wikipedia page about java)

One method would be to have a reference document and find similarities between this document and the set of documents at hand (as mentioned in the previous example). And provide a result saying the one which has maximum similarity is the most important docuemnt .

I want to identify other more efficient methods of performing this. 
please suggest other methods for finding the relevant document (in a unsupervised way if possible) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think another mechanism would be, have a dictionary of words and ranking map associated with each document.

For example, in Java complete reference book case, there will be a dictionary of keywords and its ranking.

Java-10
J2ee-5
J2SDK-10
Java5-10 etc.,

Note:If your documents are dynamic streams and names also dynamic, I am not sure how to handle it.

Comment: This sounds good.. But in this case , the user would have to know atleast a set of few keywords whereas if he has a reference he need not have any knowledge on the domain .

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your comment. But I would like to add some clarification. If 'user' in this context is document uploader, yes they need to know for which keywords their document should show up. If user is different from document uploader, they know what they are looking for (on the other hand, document uploader need to map most appropriate keyword). It is something like how we add keywords if we write blogs.

Comment: what if we make it easier for the document uploader. He need not know the key words . Let the user type in the key words and we can make the system match documents (just like how a search engine works) . The one with the maximum similarity can be judged the best . Do u think this would work ?

Comment: It should work, but the complexity I see here is, 1)we don't know what type document was uploaded by uploader 2) For each client request you need to scan through all the files for the keyword entered by user which may slow down the response time. If you really want to avoid uploader from entering keywords, the other approach may be you generate ranking system for keywords. For example if user entered "business" keyword, go through all the documents you have in system and rank them and store these ranks some where.

Comment: Sorry it seems there is limit for comment, here is continuation.   Next time if another user types same key word you don't need to rescan all the files, first check in stored ranking system and make sure highest rank file is available. If new files are there, only scan them. Does this make sense?

Comment: yes i get it.. All of them are going to be text documents(.txt) , so that should not be a problem . I came across several ranking algorithms which are quite efficient . so i guess may be this would give better results than the reference